# Split into string array only the key by comma and not values c#

Tags: strsplit

This is my String and i have problems when splitting into string array with comma seperated values for keys

> { Yr = 2019, Mth = DECEMBER , SeqN = 0, UComment = tet,tet1, OComment = test,test1, FWkMth = WK, FSafety = Y, FCustConsign = Y, FNCNRPull = 0, FNCNRPush = 0, CreatedTime = 2020-01-03 06:16:53 }

when i try to use string.Split(',') i get "Ucomment = tet","tet1" as seperate array.
But i need to have split string[] when seperated by comma

> UComment = tet,tet1
>   OComment = test,test1

I have tried using the regex ,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)" but it didnot work.

Comment: What does your expected output look like here?

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen, it is sring array and it will be like  "Yr = 2019",  "Mth = DECEMBER", "SeqN = 0", "UComment = tet,tet1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try matching on the regex pattern `\S+\s*=\s*.*?(?=\s*,\s*\S+\s*=|\s*\}$)`:

```
string input = "{ Yr = 2019, Mth = DECEMBER , SeqN = 0, UComment = tet,tet1, OComment = test,test1, FWkMth = WK, FSafety = Y, FCustConsign = Y, FNCNRPull = 0, FNCNRPush = 0, CreatedTime = 2020-01-03 06:16:53 }";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\S+\s*=\s*.*?(?=\s*,\s*\S+\s*=|\s*\}$)");
var results = regex.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

This prints:

```
Yr = 2019
Mth = DECEMBER
SeqN = 0
UComment = tet,tet1
OComment = test,test1
FWkMth = WK
FSafety = Y
FCustConsign = Y
FNCNRPull = 0
FNCNRPush = 0
CreatedTime = 2020-01-03 06:16:53
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used:

```
\S+                        match a key
\s*                        followed by optional whitespace and
=                          literal '='
\s*                        more optional whitespace
.*?                        match anything until seeing
(?=\s*,\s*\S+\s*=|\s*\}$)  that what follows is either the start of the next key/value OR
                           is the end of the input
```